# How to put useQuery to Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

How to put useQuery in a Promise? this is my sample code. I dont know how to wrap this two. please help thanks.

```
  const searchData = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(test_data);
    }, 1000);
  });
  const fetchSearchLocation = async (name) => {
    
    const { data } = await client.query({
      
      query: SEARCH_PEOPLE,
      variables: {
        name: name
      },
    });
    return data;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

**You dont need to add a promise, that is handled internally.**

example from the doc

```
 const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGS);
  if (loading) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
  return <p>{data}</p>
```